# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] on Express server

Tags: express, server, response

My backend code got the error below while trying to respond to the client request.

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:467:11)

Answer (score 0):

After searching through the internet, I came across a post that helped me in solving that problem easily. Kudos to Prosper Opara. For details refer to  https://www.codementor.io/@oparaprosper79/understanding-node-error-err_http_headers_sent-117mpk82z8